Playing safe when shortening up public key hashes
When using subtle crypto (in my case ECDSA/P-384), what exactly guarantees that a subset of the public key hash prefixed/suffixed with any symbol(s) would yield unique value (like in case with Etherium 0X + 40 symbols)? Is it backed by any fundamental research?
We all want to have as short "account names" as possible, but not shorter...Not being a mathematician, I'd like to understand how it works and what are the rules at a high level.

The public key is derived from the private key and is in itself unique as long as the private key is unique (as the EC parameters form a group). The public key is calculated by "multiplying" the private key vector with the base point of the curve.
A subset of any hash is considered to be well distributed as the hash will produce a uniform distribution. It is a common method to shorten a hash by taking the leftmost bytes from a hash. Actually, that's more or less what SHA-384 is; it's just SHA-512 with different initial values and shortened to 384 bits.
What is left is the collision resistance, which is of course half of the output size of the hash function. In this case it is 160 bits (40 hex digits = 20 bytes = 160 bits), so it has the same collision resistance of SHA-1, if SHA-1 wasn't broken. It makes sense to use a more modern and hopefully more secure hash instead of SHA-1 or RIPEMD-160 even if just 160 bits are used.

Thanks for this. SHA-1 is only known to me as something which was hacked and isn't safe to be used anymore. Can collision resistance be measured in %% - as in how much weaker it becomes as it gets shorter using 100% is a fill bodies pubkey collision resistance?

Hash algorithms lose 1 bits of security for 2 bits of output when it comes down to collision resistance, considering that the hash is secure in a cryptographic sense. Or it gets 1 bit more secure for every 2 bits of output, whichever way your are traveling. One bit of security is doubling the effort required, i.e. if $s$ is the security strength then you need $2^s$ ops to break it.

thanks, doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me still, possibly never will. It's the biggest mystery to me how can you rely on something which isn't 100% true, assuming you'll be lucky, but it seems to be the common belief. When they will invent quantum PCs it all won't make much sense why not just wait. All in all - even if those shortened keys collide, it will cause just some confusion at most as serious things would still requite full public/private keys.
